# India rail (Bhadrak-Howrah): Can I alight at any stop and then continue the journey later that day?

Tags: trains, indian-railways

I want to go To BHC/Bhadrak on 12th June but I booked the ticket to HWH/Howrah. I want to alight in BBS/Bhubaneswar for work, can i board any train through to BHC/Bhadrak using the same ticket on the same day?

Comment: Can you edit the question to make it a bit clearer, I don't want to edit it as I'm not sure exactly what you're asking. I *think* you have a ticket to somewhere (hwh = Howrah Junction?) but you're actually going to (bhc = Bhadrakh?) but you want to get off early at (bbs = Bhubaneswar?) and then get a later train but still on the same day?

Comment: We realise it's probably not your first language, but you can still use punctuation and sentences and proper/full words (not abbreviations) - it helps make communication a LOT clearer and is more likely to get answers.

Comment: If it helps, write out your entire question in your native language, and then use something like Google Translate to translate it into English. Grammar may still be a bit off, but we could work with that.

Answer (score 2):

I know your question is too old for this to be useful to you, but just as a reference, A booked ticket i.e. a reservation ticket issued for a train is valid only on that train on that date.  It can neither be used for travel in another train or another date.  point no. 649 in http://www.indianrailways.gov.in/railwayboard/uploads/codesmanual/CommManual-I/ComercialManualCh6_data.htm clarifies this.

However you or someone wanting a similar facility can make use of break journey facility (as explained in http://www.indianrail.gov.in/break_Journey.html) for a purpose similar to yours.